# Embed external image links in node fields, without downloading them to own site?

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, field

In Drupal 7;

- I want to show external images in my nodes by giving its link as "http://www.example.com/aa.jpg"
- I don't want them to download to my site
- I will make it by the fields

Is there a module for Drupal 7 doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short...yes!

You can install the [Media module](http://drupal.org/project/media) along with [Remote Stream Wrapper module](http://drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper).

When you add your new image field, choose the 'Media file selector' widget. This:

> Provides the ability to use external files with file fields without saving the files to your local files directory. Also provides a 'Remote URL' browser plugin.

A further look at the module page for Remote Stream Wrapper says it does this:

> By default the module adds support for any URL using http://, https://, or feed://

Which i think is exactly what you're after.

I'd also recommend installing the [Media Browser Plus module](http://drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) which provides a better browser for when your users are picking images.

Comment: Thank you very much. But when i add new image field with "media selector widget", it gives 5 options of "upload, library, view, web, remotefile". I select "web" and "remote file". When i create new node by using this field, i select "web" while creating the node. But after i paste image link, after saving the node, i saw that that image file was saved to my disk.

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 7 you already have Imagecache as a core module. All you have to do is to install [Imagecache External](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external). This is an utility module to allow you to use imagecache(D6)/image derivatives (D7) with external images.
After enabling the module, set the following permissions:

- View external images
- Fetch external images

**Configuration**

The module's default configuration is very restrictive.
Excluding admin user or users with the 'Bypass black/white list' permission - the default configuration of the module is to deny all requests to fetch external images.
So to get the module to work, you need to visit admin/settings/imagecache_external and either:

```
Add some domains to the whitelist -or-
Switch the mode of operation from whitelist to blacklist
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I follow this procedure I get this error on Remote URL locally

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children() (line 6517 of C:\Drupal Sites\BajaInsider\includes\common.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5982 of C:\Drupal Sites\BajaInsider\includes\common.inc).

and a dozen other illegal calls for the same variable... Using a NEX theme  template as a core. Drupal 7.36, all up to date, no mods to core, testing locally.